# What is this 'the' in "if you live in 'the city'..."?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> If you live in **the** city, you need to know that everything is noisy.

This "the" could mean both a specific city and a general city?

Comment: "*the* city" has a specific city in mind, even if not specified. The implied city could be different in example usages.

Answer (score 5):

*The* refers to something specific whether 'general' (generic) or not.

Most likely this sentence refers to a *generic* city. Thus, *the city* would be a generic noun phrase, with *the* as the definite, generic article.

This could be a used, for example  to compare life in *the (generic) city* to live in *the (generic) country*, with *country* meaning *rural area*.

> On the average, people in the US live five years longer in *the city* than they live in *the country*.

And, likewise, your sentence could be using *the city* as a definite generic noun phrase.

For the information on generic noun phrases, see [Re: A question about the generic use of articles](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html)

However, if the speaker is using *the city* to refer to a non-generic city, such as *New York City*, then *the city* is not a generic noun phrase.

Many who live near New York City refer to New York City as *the city*, and here they are not referring to a generic city. In writing, *City* would be capitalized, which also clarifies the nature of the noun phrase.

In either case, *the* refers to something *specific*.

Unfortunately, many websites use *generic* and *specific* as opposites. This is not the case, in technical terms. Thus, a noun phrase can be

1 specific, generic

*The city* is noisy. I want to live in *the country*.

*The bear* is a noisy animal. You can usually hear one before you see one.

2 specific, non-generic

*The city of Chicago* is windy.

*The bear* in *the small zoo I visited last week* is old and fat.

3 non-specific, generic

*A city* is a noisy place to live in.

*A bear* protects its young, so avoid getting close to bear cubs.

4 non-specific, non-generic

Name *a city in the US with more than one million residents*.

*A bear of his* is loose in the city.

Comment: I think "the" here is ungrammatical if you want to refer to a generic city. When you have a choice between "the" and "a", you have to use "a". That applies to "county", "state", etc. That clears any possible misunderstanding. "Country" is an exception because "in the country" is idiomatic. "In the state" could mean "in the US" and it is very misleading when you use the generic "the" before "state".

Comment: @Ranthony you are entitled to your opinion. However, it does not coincide with fact. I suggest you read, [the article](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html) I mentioned in my answer, as well as the sample sentences in my answer.

Comment: I edited my comment. There is no reason to use "the" except for "in the country" which is idiomatic. When you say "the city is noisy", you are referring to a specific city which is noisy. It is not generic. "Bear" is a completely different story.

Comment: @Ranthony You are wrong. My sentence *On the average, people in the US live five years longer in the city than they live in the country* uses two generic noun phrases: *the city* and *the country*. So, as I have said before, the *the* in *the city* could refer either to a generic city or to a non-generic city. If *the city* is one you can visit, it is not generic.

Comment: @Ranthony And, when I say *the city is noisy*, I could be referring to a generic city or a non-generic city. I could very well be referring to a generic city or to a non-generic city. Either way *the city* is a definite noun phrase, and *the* also marks for specificity.

Comment: It is not a matter of right or wrong. Your quote, "On the average...", you use the city to contrast the country. You correctly said it is a noun phrase, idiomatic. Now, contrast "A city is noisy" with "The city is noisy" and "A town is clean" with "The town is clean". In the OP's sentence, there is no reason to use "the". That's my point.

Comment: @Ranthony There may be no overt reason, but native speakers construct sentences with definite (*the*), generic noun phrases all the time.

Comment: The definite generic - implies a classification - general group, making it distinct from other groups. Hence, the example, 'The tiger is in danger of becoming extinct.' The tiger as an animal, not the elephant, not the rhinoceros, not any other animal.

Comment: This is a very good answer. One small but occasionally important addition, if you are in the UK, "The city" can be as described above, or it can refer to the financial district of the city of London. For example, a news article about shares will often start "in the city, the 100 share index closed up 50 points". If it's used this way, it is usually obvious from context because it will be about financial dealings of some kind.

Comment: @JosephRogers The street could refer to "Wall Street" in New York in the same way as you described "the" city.

Comment: @Rathony - In the U.S. there has long been a perceived divide between culture, lifestyle, etc. of those who live in cities vs. those who live in rural areas (a.k.a., 'the country'). Each type of dweller views the other with a mixture of curiosity and contempt. City dwellers see themselves as more educated and progressive, country dwellers see themselves as more practical and possessing more common sense and better moral values.

It is, therefore, quite common to refer to 'the city' or 'the country' in generic form. Also, see http://www.metrolyrics.com/in-the-city-lyrics-joe-walsh.html

Comment: @dixonge I appreciate the comment. Nice song, also. My life has been divided between the city and the country most my life, and there is definitely a cultural difference.

Comment: @JosephRogers: note that, when written down, the [City of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_London) is always written with a capital 'C'.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff you're right of course, I hadn't thought of that since I almost exclusively encounter it on the Radio 4 news!